# Are there any default extension or filename that is git ignored by default?

Tags: git

I'm wondering if there's any pattern that is ignored by git without any previous .gitignore file has been created locally or globally?

I need to run a script that temporarily creates a file inside directories, but I don't want it to be committed by accident, editing the gitignore in this case is not an option.

One idea is create files inside the `.git` folder, is this safe or there's any change that I would break git?

Comment: The main drawback to stuffing things inside `.git` is that you don't know what a future Git version will consider offensive or overwrite-able. For instance, in Git 1.7, you might have created a file `.git/worktrees` to put data into, but then when Git 2.5 came out and used `.git/worktrees/` to hold information about added work-trees, you'd be stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.git/info/exclude` so that it's only for that repo.

Answer (score 2):

`.git` is un-addable at *all* levels. You can safely create a new directory called `.git` *anywhere* inside the repository, and you don't have to worry about messing with the *real* `.git` directory.

Comment: I have been searching for this answer for the past half hour.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the actual question, *kinda*... Only the `.git` folder is ignored by default. All others are deamed potentially important for the source-base unless configured otherwise within the repository or at a global level.

The only reason why this is a "kinda" answer is because the `.git` folder contains the repository history and is therefore managed by `git` itself. Though you can safely add some files to `.git`, it can be risky.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this it is by adding a global git ignore and add this file pattern.

1. create a file out side all the repos

   `touch ~/.gitignore`
2. add the pattern inside this file
3. set the git config to use this file 
   `git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore`

Answer (score 0):

It's okay to create files in `.git` so that they won't be committed. But there is a risk that the reserved files in `.git` might be edited or deleted by accident and therefore the repository gets corrupted. Another option is to create files outside the repository and I think the system temporary folder is a safer place.